# How to deal with rapid acceleration/deceleration from physics forces?

Tags: physics, lua, love2d

I'm working on a game in LOVE2D using Lua, where you pilot a drilling vehicle.  The idea is that as you drill into different surfaces, you speed up/slow down depending on how dense that surface is.  I'm simulating it using drag forces, something like this:

```
engineForce = engineForce + userInput * dt -- increase the engine speed based on user input
dragForce = .25 * dragCoefficient * speed^2 -- a simple implementation of the drag equation
acceleration = engineForce - dragForce
speed = speed + acceleration*dt
```

What's supposed to happen is velocity will increase until dragForce = engineForce and it maintains speed. This mostly works except occasionally it gets into a weird feedback loop where speed overshoots slightly (not sure if it's due to a rounding error or what) so drag becomes stronger than the engine causing it to decelerate. But because it decelerated, drag decreases and now the engine is stronger than drag, causing it to accelerate again.  And again it will overshoot the target, causing the process to repeat again.

Does anyone know best practices for programming physics like this?

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone's curious, I think I figured it out.  I calculated a "terminal velocity" for a given engineForce, that is the speed where drag and the engine would balance out (in this case that's sqrt(4*engineForce/dragCoefficient)) and cap your velocity at that.  So far, it seems to work!

Comment: Another option (though more complicated) is to look at the problem as a differential equation. [Your acceleration formula gives us an equation for `dv/dt` in terms of `v`, which we can solve to find that the speed `v` must follow a curve described by the hyperbolic tangent function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=v%28t%29%27+%3D+a+-+d*v%28t%29%5E2). You can use that to step forward by a given time step, factoring in continuously changing acceleration over the interval, rather than treating the instantaneous acceleration as constant for the interval (which is what causes the oscillation)